# Microsoft-teams bot notify editing the message

Tags: microsoft-teams

When a Microsoft-teams bot is added to an existing message on a channel, by editing the message, would it be possible to notify the bot about the message?

Answer (score 0):

Bot doesn't get any activity when message is edited or updated.This is the intended behaviour of the bot